# pip packages import fails when called from PHP

Tags: php, python, linux, nginx, pip

I try to run a python script on a shared webserver.
it runs fine in SSH like:

> ./../python/bin/python cgi-bin/script.py

However when I want it to run through PHP the python script runs until it imports pip packages.

the error comes from importing installed pip packages.

I tried fooling around with permissions, put all files and directories to 755 and chmod x
and I tried manually and freshly installing python 2.7 (webserver runs python 2.6 by default, hence the python call "./../python/bin/python", I could not install 3.5 I got a lot of errors and a timeout.)
I don't have sudo rights.

script.py

```
print "I will be displayed! yay it works\n"

# import the necessary packages
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2
import os

print "I won't be displayed, it does not work!\n"
```

runpython.php

```
<?php
$query='./../python/bin/python cgi-bin/script.py 2>&1';
$command=escapeshellcmd($query);
$output=shell_exec($command);
echo $output;

$last_line=system($query, $retval);
echo '</pre>
<hr />Last line of the output: ' . $last_line . '
<hr />Return value: ' . $retval;
?>
```

I expect both prints to be displayed from the python script, however it only displays the first print.
something goes wrong at importing the installed pip packages.

```
Error message (output):
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: pthread_create failed for thread 15 of 20: Resource temporarily unavailable
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: RLIMIT_NPROC 25 current, 30 max
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: pthread_create failed for thread 16 of 20: Resource temporarily unavailable
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: RLIMIT_NPROC 25 current, 30 max
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: pthread_create failed for thread 17 of 20: Resource temporarily unavailable
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: RLIMIT_NPROC 25 current, 30 max
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: pthread_create failed for thread 18 of 20: Resource temporarily unavailable
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: RLIMIT_NPROC 25 current, 30 max
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: pthread_create failed for thread 19 of 20: Resource temporarily unavailable
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: RLIMIT_NPROC 25 current, 30 max


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cgi-bin/bw-colorization/bw2color_image.py", line 13, in 
    import numpy as np
  File "/home4/johndooc/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in 
    from . import core
  File "/home4/johndooc/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 95, in 
    from . import numeric
  File "/home4/johndooc/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 39, in 
    from ._internal import TooHardError, AxisError
  File "/home4/johndooc/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/_internal.py", line 16, in 
    import ctypes
  File "/home4/johndooc/python/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 549, in 
    CFUNCTYPE(c_int)(lambda: None)
MemoryError

Last line of the output: MemoryError 
Return value: 1MemoryError
```

Answer (score 0):

The user used to installed python packages have to be the same than the user who execute the python script. 
Here it is the "webserver user" who execute the script and I think you installed packages with an other user